# Generalized inner product

Tags: calculus, vector-spaces, inner-products

I'm told that an integral of the form $$\int_{-\infty}^\infty f^*(x)g(x)dx$$ is just a generalization of the standard inner product of two vectors in $\Bbb C^n$: $$\langle v,w\rangle = \sum_{i=0}^n v^*_iw_i$$ and I do see how they are similar.  Both sum over the components of the "vectors" (one just has uncountably many components).

But the integral "product" has something that the sum "product" doesn't -- a $dx$.  So not only are you multiplying the components (values) of the two functions together, but you're scaling them by that infinitesimal $dx$.  I see why we probably need that, if we tried to just sum $f$ and $g$ like $\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} f^*(x)g(x)$ *without* the infinitesimal, the integral would almost certainly blow up.

So can anyone explain why we consider the integral inner product to be a generalization of the sum inner product?

Comment: Take $\Delta i = (i)-(i-1) = 1$, and write $$\langle v,w\rangle = \sum_{i=0}^n v^*(i)w(i)\Delta i$$ Now they match. A discrete sum **is** an integral, using an integrator that has a jump discontinuity at each integer. In other words, we have $d\alpha(x)=1$.

Comment: Wow.  I didn't consider that.  Thanks. :)

Answer (score 1):

Forget $dx$. The case is the following: $C^0([0,1])$ (for simplicity) is a vector space, and

$$C^0([0,1]) \times C^0([0,1]) \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$$
$$ (f,g) \mapsto \int_0^1 fg$$

is a bilinear map which is non-degenerate, and this is the *definition* of inner product: a generalization of the standard inner product on $\mathbb{R}^n$ ($\sum x_iy_i$) in the sense that it also satisfies the properties: bilinearity and non-degeneracy. If you want to consider $\mathbb{C}$, you also put in the hypothesis of anti-symmetry and adjust the linearity hypothesis to only hold on the first variable.